# SQL Server backup & restore daily strategy

Tags: sql-server

We are in an environment where we need to restore the production db the size of around 600GB from daily backup to our UAT server.

We have currently do full backup and restore and as database grows it has slowed down the overall performance. Im not a DBA and wonder whats the best strategy to optimise this process.

Occasionally  we also have experience very slow restore even after I enabled the instant file initialisation. Its processing in a normal speed but all of sudden from like 50 percent it processes extremely slow. Any idea where to begin the investigation ?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.+

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. Don't restore a daily backup every day.  Your data won't change overnight if you aren't using it.
2. Use incremental backups(backups of files that have changed since the last backup) daily, and full backups(backups of everything) weekly or monthly.
3. Use a RAID for redundancy rather than backups.
4. Try to bring up your concerns with the administrator.
5. If you have multiple servers, check if more than one is accessing the backup at a time.